# Obtain email address of Foursquare developer account

Tags: foursquare

I have the client id/secret, but not the email address that was used to create the app in the developer portal. This is prevent me from verifying the account in order to address the recent rate limit policies. Is there something I can do to learn this email address and then use the reset password option?